# Replacing HTMLWorker with XML Worker in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Currently I'm using this code :

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
using (var htmlViewReader = new StringReader(htmlText)) {
    using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDocument)) {
        css.LoadStyle("body", "style", "width: 100%;");
        //  css.LoadStyle(".fr", "style", "float: right;");
        css.LoadStyle("fr","float","right");
        css.LoadStyle(".fl", "style", "float: left; width: 20%;");
        css.LoadStyle("container", "style", "width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;");
        css.LoadStyle("header", "style", "margin-top: 75px; width: 100%;");
        css.LoadStyle("header name", "style", "font-size: 18px;");
        css.LoadStyle("footer", "style", "border-top: 2px solid #333; text-align: center;");
        css.LoadTagStyle("p", "style", "padding: 0 45px 0 25px; color: #666;");
        css.LoadTagStyle("a", "style", "color: #666;");
        css.LoadStyle("deposit", "style", "font-size: 22px; width: 100%; color: #999; font-weight: bold; float:right;");
        css.LoadStyle("cl", "style", "clear: both;");
        css.LoadStyle("title", "style", "margin: 0 45px 0 25px; border-bottom: 2px solid #333; font-weight: bold;");
        css.LoadTagStyle("ul", "style", "list-style-type: none; width: 50%;");
        css.LoadTagStyle("ul li", "style", "line-height: 25px;");
        css.LoadTagStyle("li", "style", "line-height: 25px;");
        htmlWorker.SetStyleSheet(css);
        //htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);
    }
}
```

However, as documented `HTMLWorker` doesn't parse CSS styles.

I need to replace it with XML Worker. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What did you try? Did you read the documentation? http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html

Comment: i m trying html to pdf with css, and i use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3 article. but htmlworker not working with css.i hear xmlworker for html with css.and i must convert htmlworker to xmlworker. sory for my english

Answer (score 1):

To use CSS with XML Worker, you can load it from an external css file:

```
public static class XMLWorkerUtils
{
    public static ICssFile GetCssFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            return XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can define it inline:

```
var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
// cssResolver.AddCss(XMLWorkerUtils.GetCssFile(@"c:\path\pdf.css"));
cssResolver.AddCss(@"code
                         {
                            padding: 2px 4px;
                            color: #d14;
                            white-space: nowrap;
                            background-color: #f7f7f9;
                            border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
                         }",
                         "utf-8", true);
```

Then inject this cssResolver into the CssResolverPipeline. Read more about it in [its official documentation here](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-7).